# JDBC dynamic query, only put value to string if not -1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with JDBC and java. 
I have a Query like this:

```sql
String updateSql = "UPDATE league SET season=?, playedMatches=?, percentHomeWins=?, percentDraws=?, percentAwayWins=?, averageGoalsPerGame=?, averageGoalsHomePerGame=?, averageGoalsAwayPerGame=?, percentOverOne=?, percentOverTwo=?, percentOverThree=?, percentBothTeamsScored=?, scoredGoalsTotal=?  " + whereClause + " and country='" + l.getCountry() + "'";
```

all values after "season" can either be a number >= 0 or -1. -1 means, that there is no value. the values come from a class that holds data (like an object model).
I want only the values in my query, which are >= 0. The other one should not be in the query, because they replace data in the database, which they should not.

Can anyone help me archiving this?

Comment: If you know to use `?` parameter markers and `PreparedStatement`, why on earth are you using string concatenation to build the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: *FYI:* An `UPDATE` *statement* is not a *query*. Only `SELECT` statements are queries.

Comment: I know, how to do this, but I think there should be an easier way, how to do this and exclude a value from an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to dynamically build the SQL statement, e.g.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE league SET season=?");
List<Integer> numValues = new ArrayList<>();
if (l.getPlayedMatches() != -1) {
    sql.append(", playedMatches=?");
    numValues.add(l.getPlayedMatches());
}
if (l.getPercentHomeWins() != -1) {
    sql.append(", percentHomeWins=?");
    numValues.add(l.getPercentHomeWins());
}
// ... more code ...
sql.append(whereClause)
   .append(" and country=?");
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString())) {
    int paramIdx = 0;
    stmt.setInt(++paramIdx, l.getSeason());
    for (Integer numValue : numValues)
        stmt.setInt(++paramIdx, numValue);
    stmt.setString(++paramIdx, l.getCountry());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: THIS is a very useful awnser. Thank you very much!